# How to configure home directories that are, at the same time, writable for apache

Tags: apache, permissions, apache2, home-directory, writable

I've configured my apache to serve the `public_html` folders inside each user.
Then I've configured virtual hosts that will access those folders.

So the current status is depicted in the following example: I have a domain (`foo-bar.com`) that is served by a virtual host and points to the `/home/foo-bar/public_html` folder. This is happening for several domain<->user pairs.

My problem is when the site has to upload some files to, for example, `/home/foo-bar/public_html/contents`. My solution so far has been to change ownership of that folder to the apache user and group, but this makes it impossible for the user to, among other things, upload files to that folder via FTP.

What are the best practices in such cases? How to solve this?

Thank you.

**FURTHER DEVELOPMENT**

I've managed to do it by changing the group of the `/home/foo-bar/public_html/contents` to the apache user and adding writing permissions to the group. This way the folder is writable for the apache user and its owner.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION (not yet implemented nor tested)**

Someone gave me an answer that seems to me the best solution so far for this question: to setup virtual users and and accounts with pureftp and mysql.

Since I'm using vsftp, I found this link that might be usefull for someone:

http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/

Answer (score 0):

You can set that folder to 777, the user and apache-user with 777 permisions can write in that folder.

Comment: That's precicely what I don't want to do. To me that's a huge security risk that I don't want to take.

Comment: Not the user folder, the content folder `/home/foo-bar/public_html/contents`

Comment: Still, I'm not comfortable with the idea of having several folders with 777 permissions (I have several users with sites).
Besides that, it always require manual intervention if the site changes or adds upload features to other folders.

Comment: a better solution is to do what I described in the edit above: to change the group of the folder to the apache user and give writing permissions to the group. This solves the 777 question but it's still a manual solution, hence my question on changing the primary group of the user to the apache group. This way all the folders created would automatically have the apache group as their group.

Comment: Having all users with the apache group as primary group has the inconvenience of every user being able to read and write on any other user's folder, since they all belong to the apache group that has read and write permissions. It's not an option.

Comment: I think 777 (or 755) in that folder this is a better solution, apache user must have permisions to read the folder and to write in that folder, also the user. In a hosting your folder is owned by the ftp user, not the apache user, if you need write in a folder or file with apache, you set the permisions in that folder, and the user can do it.